# How To Remember The שבע מצוות בני נח?

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah, noachide-laws, memory

I once heard an easy way to remember the שבע מצוות בני נח:
א = אבר מו החי
ב = ברכת השם
ג = גזל
ד = דינים
ה = הרג
ו = גיל**ו**י ערי**ו**ת
ז = עבודה **ז**רה

I am not sure if I am remembering ג ו & ז right - I don't know if ג is גזל or גילוי עריות.

I would love it if somebody could either fill in mine or have a different way of easily remembering the שבע מצוות בני נח!

Comment: I’ve seen people usually just say aleph, bet, gimel, dalet, and the big 3. So the letters stand for what you put, and the big 3 are simply the 3 sins that a Jew must die for rather than commit them (murder, adultery, and idolatry), also known as יהרג ואל יעבור

Comment: I've heard it mostly like you said, though ending with ועבודה זרה and זנות.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an English-language acronym for the Seven Laws of Noah, CHABLIS works:

- **C**ourts of Justice
- **H**omicide
- **A**dultery (or sexual immorality in general)
- **B**lasphemy
- **L**imb from a living animal
- **I**dolatry
- **S**tealing

Comment: Or CABLISH or BICLASH etc. Is CHABLIS a particularly meaningful combination?

Comment: @DoubleAA don't think so

Comment: @Daniel ben Noach  Thanks!

Comment: @DoubleAA: Except for being a valid dictionary word, not really.  I just did a brute-force search to find a word that fit.  An alternative permutation I found was "Blasphemy, Idolatry, Theft, Courts of justice, Homicide, Eating a limb from a living animal, and Sexual Immorality", but I decided to go with the less-rude acronym.